# draggable jquery-ui-dialog with textarea in mobile devices using touch-punch plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-plugins

I use jquery-ui-touch-punch plugin, so that I could drag my jquery-ui-dialog properly on Iphone/Android etc.

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() { 
    this.uiDialog.draggable();
};
```

It works properly on devices, but the problem is I cannot use textarea inside the dialog (*cannot type anything*). When I tap on the textarea nothing happends.

I am aware that any part of the dialog I touch is subject for dragging. Actually thats what I want since I am using big dialog, it allows the user to drag even not using the header/top of the diaolog.

My question is, is their a way where I can use textarea as well as dragging function is the same?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried http://jquerymobile.com/
its also the same with jquery UI but built for mobile